# PureConfig ConfigLoader in Scala

Tags: scala, pureconfig

I am following this link to use pureconfig to load the data 
https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-case-classes.html.
Here is my code

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import pureconfig._
private case class SampleConf(foo: Int, bar: String)
object TestConfigLoad {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    loadConfig[SampleConf](ConfigFactory.parseString("{ FOO: 2, BAR: two }"))
  }
}
```

When I run it  , I am getting this error

```
Error:scalac: Error: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tl$1()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tl$1()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
    at shapeless.LazyMacros$DerivationContext$State.addDependency(lazy.scala:363)
```

These are the entries in the pom file

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                     <version>2.11.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.pureconfig</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pureconfig_2.11</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.0</version>
                </dependency>
           <dependency>

            <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzled-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lihaoyi</groupId>
            <artifactId>sourcecode_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: have you tried `ConfigFactory.parseString("{ foo: 2, bar: two }")` (names are lowercase)

Comment: yes. It gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

You have to match the Scala versions. Cannot mix 2.10 (scala-library) and 2.11 (pureconfig_2.11).

Unless you have a good reason, use the latest stable version (2.12.8 currently)

Comment: I tried using scala version 2.11.7. It gave the same error . I edited the pom above

Comment: Do you have any other Scala dependencies in your pom.xml ?

Comment: I have couple more dependencies. All of them are point to 2.11

Comment: Since pureConfig use Scala 2.11.11, while you use 2.11.7. Can you try 2.11.11?

Comment: I tried with scala 2.11.11 it did not work. Same error

Comment: What version of shapeless is being pulled in?